# Download Campaign Performance Reports using Bings Ads in PHP

Tags: php, download, fopen, ads, bing-api

I was struck in this since a weeks. Please tell me if any one can help me out from this.

I tried [this samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/bing/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f) they given. I'm trying to download only campaign performance reports, Where i'm able to download a zip file which has a csv file in it. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-reporting-request-and-download-a-keyword-performance-report-in-php.aspx) is the another direct example i followed for keywords and did the same way for campaign performance. Which giving me a link to download the reports. When i'm trying to download the url manually i can download but I cannot download it through my code.

```
function DownloadFile($reportDownloadUrl, $downloadPath) {
    if (!$reader = fopen($reportDownloadUrl, 'rb')) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to open URL " . $reportDownloadUrl . ".");
    }
    if (!$writer = fopen($downloadPath, 'wb')){
        fclose($reader);
        throw new Exception("Failed to create ZIP file " . $downloadPath . ".");
    }
    $bufferSize = 100 * 1024;
    while (!feof($reader)) {
        if (false === ($buffer = fread($reader, $bufferSize))) {
            fclose($reader);
            fclose($writer);
            throw new Exception("Read operation from URL failed.");
        }

        if (fwrite($writer, $buffer) === false) {
            fclose($reader);
            fclose($writer);
            $exception = new Exception("Write operation to ZIP file failed.");
        }
    }
    fclose($reader);
    fflush($writer);
    fclose($writer);
}
```

But I couldn't download the file. I can't move forward from there so any help like downloading reports in any-other form or the simple code changes in current method is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this I also had problems with the DownloadFile function so replaced this with a different version

```
function DownloadFile($reportDownloadUrl, $downloadPath) {
    $url    = $reportDownloadUrl;
    // Example for the path would be in this format
    // $path = '/xxx/yyy/reports/keywordperf.zip';
    // using the server path and not relative to the file
    $path   = $downloadPath;

    $fp     = fopen($path, 'w');
    $ch     = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    if($result = curl_exec($ch)) {
        $status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $status = false;
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    return status;
}
```